# Self Join with on different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT R1.RELATIONSHIP_ID, R1.SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID, R2.BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID
FROM RELATIONSHIP R1 JOIN RELATIONSHIP R2
ON (R1.RELATIONSHIP_ID = R2.RELATIONSHIP_ID)
ORDER BY SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID;
```

For the tables:
1. `RELATIONSHIP`: Columns: `RELATIONSHIP_ID, SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID, BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID` ...
2. `ACCOUNT`: `ACCOUNT_ID, XX_ACCOUNT_ID` ....

and gives the result correctly so far

[image: result sampe]

However, what I want is more complicated. I need to replace the second and third columns with a column `called XX_ACOUNT_ID` to be shown **twice**. Each `SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID` and `BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID` has a unique `XX_ACCOUNT_ID` and a unique `ACCOUNT_ID`. `XX_ACCOUNT_ID` belongs to the table `ACCOUNTS` in which there is `ACCOUNT_ID` (`SUUPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID & BUYER_ACCONT_ID` are referenced from this column) and `XX_ACCOUNT_ID`. I'm a bit confused that does it need nested self-join or multiple inner joins? or subqueries to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your tables an columns. Try to 'draw' them, like you did the query result.

Comment: Please specify all the columns you need in output.

Comment: The question is updated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `R1.Supplier_Account_ID` and `R2.Buyer_Account_ID` will always exist in the referenced tables, multiple inner joins should work. Try something like this:

```
SELECT R1.RELATIONSHIP_ID, AcctSupp.XX_ACOUNT_ID, AcctBuyer.XX_ACOUNT_ID
FROM RELATIONSHIP R1
JOIN RELATIONSHIP R2 ON (R1.RELATIONSHIP_ID = R2.RELATIONSHIP_ID)
JOIN Accounts AcctSupp ON R1.SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID = AcctSupp.Account_ID
JOIN Accounts AcctBuyer ON R2.BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID = AcctBuyer.Account_ID
ORDER BY SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID;
```

If there's any chance the values won't exist in the referenced tables, use left joins instead:

```
SELECT R1.RELATIONSHIP_ID, AcctSupp.XX_ACOUNT_ID, AcctBuyer.XX_ACOUNT_ID
FROM RELATIONSHIP R1
JOIN RELATIONSHIP R2 ON (R1.RELATIONSHIP_ID = R2.RELATIONSHIP_ID)
LEFT JOIN Accounts AcctSupp ON R1.SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID = AcctSupp.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN Accounts AcctBuyer ON R2.BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID = AcctBuyer.Account_ID
ORDER BY SUPPLIER_ACCOUNT_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but I don't see why you need a self join:

```
SELECT R.Relationship_Id,
    Supplier.xx_account_id sup_id,
    Buyer.xx._account_id buy_id
FROM Relationship AS R
JOIN Accounts AS Buyer
    ON R.Buyer_account_Id = Buyer.Account_Id
JOIN Accounts AS Supplier
    ON R.Supplier_account_Id = Supplier.Account_Id
```

Comment: isn't this self-join when you join accounts twice, once as a Buyer and once as a Supplier ??. I need it because I need to project the same column twice from the same table via particular relationship between them. cheers

Comment: +1 If `Relationship_Id` is the primary key of `Relationship`, self-joining is useless.